# use const char array in snprintf in c

Tags: c, arrays, char, printf, constants

I'm very new comer to C. I've this type of code and when I tried to execute it this warning message showed up "passing argument 1 of 'snprintf' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type" and nothing happened.

What I did wrong?
Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  const char *msg[3] = {"Hello", "Good Morning", "Hello World"};
  const char *strings[];


  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
  snprintf(strings[i], 20, "%s %d", msg[i], i);

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
  printf("strings[%d]: %s\n", i, strings[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`snprintf(strings[i], 20, "%s %d", msg[i], i);`

that tries to write into `strings[i]`. Since it's been declared as constant, compiler just refuses to do that because it violates the contract.

But here, it's even more serious: `strings[i]` doesn't have any allocated memory for the strings or even the pointers (!), so removing the `const` qualifier would result in undefined behaviour when running your program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for each string you want to print, like this

```
char *strings[3];
for (i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i) {
    size_t length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s %d", msg[i], i);
    strings[i] = malloc(length + 1);
    if (string[i] != NULL) {
        snprintf(strings[i], length, "%s %d", msg[i], i);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 3 ; ++i) {
    if (string[i] != NULL) {
        printf("string[%d]: %s\n", i, strings[i]);
    }
}
```

In the first part, we allocate 3 poitners on the stack. And then, for every string we first compute the length, and then `snprintf()` into the successfuly allocated memory.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to allocate space dynamically.  An automatic array works fine as long as you can predict (a bound on) how much space you'll need.  (And as long as you don't need the data to have a longer lifetime than an automatic array provides.)

Comment: @Adam, do not forget to call 1 `free()` for every `malloc()`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi, I don't have good knowledge in C yet. what did you mean by "do not forget to call 1 free() for every malloc()"? Can you please tell me?

Comment: `malloc()` allocates memory in a way, that it becomes your responsability to realease it back to the operating system. Not calling `free()` would cause all this memory to remain allocated for your program until your program exits, so you MUST `free()` it when you no longer need it. Search google for the `free()` function.